# Should I fix all warnings that Android Studio shows, or just suppress them?

Tags: java, android, warnings

I just completed a small Android app that has a ton of warnings ('possible NPE', 'use Locale in SimpleDateFormat', etc). Obviously, these warnings aren't very pretty to look at. I know that some people choose to suppress warnings, and in some cases that is the right way to go, but is it any good to suppress all warnings or should I go ahead and try to correct as many as I can, such as adding if-not-null conditions before each possible NPE, even if I am fairly certain that statement would never throw up a NPE, which would mean that I am simply adding another function call that on aggregation with other if-not-null conditions could probably slow down my app by some degree?

Answer (score 5):

You should fix them.  Or at least *understand* them before you decide to suppress them.

In most cases, compiler warnings are telling you something important.  Ignore them and you are liable to end up with undesirable behavior; e.g. applications that crash, or that annoy users by using the wrong format when displaying dates.

Some warnings can be safely ignored / suppressed *in some contexts*, but you need to understand them before you can decide is suppression is safe.

Answer (score 1):

Suppressing or ignoring a lint warning is not always good, for example for a NPE you should check for NPE if the lint shows a warning. you can ignore warnings for setting gravity for a view like `Gravity.LEFT` as lint tells you to change it to `Gravity.START`, if you don't want to support RTL you can ignore it or suppress it. Whether to ignore a lint warning or not is up to you to decide. if you want to ignore all lint warnings just ignore it and as you said too many lint warnings in a source file is not pretty. Let your logic decide what to do when you see a lint warning. Good luck and happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple: a good craftsman keeps his work setup in perfect order.

Once you allow for a few warnings, they will start piling up. And thing is: the occasional real problem pointed out in a warning will get overlooked in that pile of mess.

There you go for a *zero tolerance* policy. 0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 commented out lines,...

And you strive to *fix* problems instead of suppressing them. Sometimes you have to silence the warning, but that is always your last choice.